# Valiedate field on blur of another field in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation, email

I  must validate a field when I leave another field...
I let you see my code:

```
<input data-ng-model="invitation.Email" name="email" type="email" data-ng-required="true" 
    data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'mousedown blur' }" />

<input data-ng-model="invitation.EmailConfirmation" name="email_confirmation" type="email" 
    data-ng-required="true" data-match="invitation.Email" data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'mousedown blur' }" />

<span data-ng-show="presenta_amico_form.email_confirmation.$error.mismatch" class="error">Email mismatch</span>
```

So, for example... I write my `Email`, and that's Ok... then I write my `ConfirmationEmail` but the error "Email mismatch" appear because I see that I was wrong in typing the `Email` field. So I correct the `Email` field but the error does not disappear because I have to focus and blur the `EmailConfirmation` field.

I do not like this and I would like that the `ConfirmationEmail` is validated also when the `Email` field lose focus.

How can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an [ngBlur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) handler to the second field and manually apply the validation e.g.

```
<input data-ng-model="invitation.Email" name="email" type="email" data-ng-required="true" 
data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'mousedown blur' }" ng-blur="checkMatch()" />
```

Comment: the `invitation.Email` is still `undefined` when I go in `checkMatch()` method... perhaps because I have `data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'mousedown blur' }"`? So, perhaps It execute before `ng-blur` and just later the update?

Comment: both model update and checkMatch are being invoked on blur. It could be that angular hasn't yet digested the changes to the model by the time you inspect the value. You could try calling `$scope.$apply()` before you inspect the value of `invitation.Email`

Comment: an alternative approach would be set up a watch on both properties and perform the validation in there. Something along the lines of: `scope.watch('invitation.Email', checkMatch); scope.watch('invitation.EmailConfirmation', checkMatch);`